# HTTP to HTTPS redirect Vagrant

Tags: django, apache, vagrant, virtualhost, portforwarding

So I've been having an issue with Vagrant and Port Forwarding...

Currently, Vagrant is already forwarding ports 80 -> 8080 and 443 -> 8443. Issue is, I don't want a client to have to type ports 8443 and 8080 to access my web page. So now, the client has to type in 127.0.0.1:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8443 to access the webpages.

How would I go about changing this? My current stack is VM, Vagrant, Apache, Django.

I have 2 VHosts setup. Heres my sites-available/mysite.com file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
              ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
              #ServerName  spritebots.com
              #ServerAlias www.spritebots.com
              ServerName 127.0.0.1
              ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
              ProxyRequests off
              ProxyPreserveHost On
              ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8443
              ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443

              #Redirect permanent / https://127.0.0.1:8443
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
              WSGIDaemonProcess spritebots
              WSGIProcessGroup spritebots
              WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/spritebots/apps/wsgi.py

              ServerAdmin  webmaster@example.com
              #ServerName   spritebots.com
              #ServerAlias  www.spritebots.com
              ServerName  127.0.0.1
              ServerAlias 127.0.0.1

              DocumentRoot /var/www/spritebots/

              Alias /media/ /var/www/spritebots/static/media/
              Alias /static/ /var/www/spritebots/static/

              <Directory /var/www/spritebots/static>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
              </Directory>

              <Directory /var/www/spritebots/static/media>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
              </Directory>

              SSLEngine on
              SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/spritebots.crt
              SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/spritebots.key

</VirtualHost>
```

So I bought a domain name, spritebots.com and I can't even get spritebots.com to point to 127.0.0.1:8443.

But for now, I would like for anyone visiting my site at 127.0.0.1, to be redirected 127.0.0.1:8443, then mask the port number. Basically like how every production web page is with HTTPS enabled.

Does a majority of developers/companies use vagrant or VMs for production web sites? Because I feel that Vagrant's port forwarding is messing this up. Or it's more possibly me just being ignorant of web development. :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a special [loop back address](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), it always refer to the current machine. You need to use the public IP address to refer to it in the DNS entry or if you want to access your machine by its IP.

Comment: oh yes. I understand that. I type in 'myipaddress' to actually view my website in production. I figure it's similar to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In your Vagrantfile, you can assign your VM a private network IP, by dropping in:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
```

Then you don't have to mess with ports.